# Using Mayer-Vietoris to compute Homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the following topological space $X$, which consists of a Klein bottle with two discs glued inside.

[image]

I am trying to compute the cellular homology of this space. Two approaches:

- direct approach: let $f_1$ be the barrel of the Klein Bottle, $f_2$ and $f_3$ be the two discs, $e_1$ be the rim of the cylinder that is glued together to obtain the Klein Bottle, $e_2$ the seam of the cylinder, and $v_1$ the (only) vertex.

  I obtain a chain complex $\langle f_1, f_2, f_3\rangle \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\ 0& 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}}\langle e_1, e_2  \rangle \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\end{pmatrix}}\langle v_1\rangle$, which leads to betti numbers $(1, 1, 2)$ and $\chi(X)=2$ over $\mathbf F_2$.
- using Mayer-Vietoris sequence: Cover $X$ by the Klein Bottle $K$ and by the sphere $S^2$ spanned by the two discs inside. We have $K\cap S^2\simeq S^1$, thus the MV-sequence is the exact sequence

  $$\begin{matrix}&0&\to& \mathbf Z&\to&H_2(X)&\to\\
      \to&\mathbf Z&\to&\mathbf Z\oplus\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z&\to&H_1(X)&\to\\
      \to&\mathbf Z&\to&\mathbf Z&\to&H_0(X)&\to & 0\end{matrix}$$

  or, to take a field,

  $$\begin{matrix}&0&\to& \mathbf F_2&\to&H_2(X)&\to\\
      \to&\mathbf F_2&\to&\mathbf F_2^2&\to&H_1(X)&\to\\
      \to&\mathbf F_2&\to&\mathbf F_2&\to&H_0(X)&\to & 0\end{matrix}$$

  However, $\chi(K\cap S^2)=0, \chi(K)+\chi(S^2)=1$, thus we would have $\chi(X)=1$, which is not compatible with the direct approach.

*Question:* Where is my misconception?

Comment: I think your direct approach has a problem. CW-complexes are built inductively from lower dimensional to higher dimensional cells, and the higher dimensional cells have their boundary atached to lower dimensional cells. However, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are not atached to any 1-cell in your complex. Try building the 0-skeleton, then the 1-skeleton and so on.

Comment: @Javi: Maybe the picture badly shows what I had in mind. To clarify, let the two discs $f_2,f_3$ both be glued to $e_1$ such that there intersection is just $e_1$. (i.e., I glue $S^2=f_1\cup_{e_1}f_2$ into the cylinder along $e_1$).

Comment: If you collapse both discs to a point (which is a homotopy equivalence), and then collapse a segment in the middle cylinder joining the two collapsed discs, you get that your space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^2$, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Nearly, I would suggest using your collapsing one obtains $S^2\vee S^2/~$ where additionally the two poles opposite to the gluing point are identified. Using the MVS 

$$\begin{matrix}&0&\to& \mathbf Z^2&\to&H_2(X)&\to\\
    \to&0 &\to& 0&\to&H_1(X)&\to\\
    \to&\mathbf Z^2&\to&\mathbf Z^2&\to&\mathbf Z&\to & 0\end{matrix}$$

the space would have Betti numbers $(1,1,2)$, which are yet another one. What the...?